# Counting the number of products per date and get values per product in column

Tags: r

I have a table where the rows are transactions and columns are products bought in that transaction.

An example:

| Date | Transaction | product 1 | product 2 | product 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1 | 1 | Apple | Banana |  |
| 1-1 | 2 | Orange |  |  |
| 1-1 | 3 | Apple | Orange |  |
| 1-2 | 4 |  |  |  |
| 1-2 | 5 | Apple | Banana |  |
| 1-3 | 6 | orange | Apple | Banana |

I want to know how many products were sold on what day. So that I will get a table as such:

| Date | Apple | Banana | Orange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1-2 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 1-3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

The challenge is, however, that there are a lot of products. Hence I won't be able to manually type them out in order for them to count.

Is anyone able to help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~Date, ~Transaction, ~product.1, ~product.2, ~product.3,
  "1-1",           1L,    "Apple",   "Banana",         NA,
  "1-1",           2L,   "Orange",         NA,         NA,
  "1-1",           3L,    "Apple",   "Orange",         NA,
  "1-2",           4L,         NA,         NA,         NA,
  "1-2",           5L,    "Apple",   "Banana",         NA,
  "1-3",           6L,   "Orange",    "Apple",   "Banana"
  )

data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Date, Transaction)) %>%
  count(Date, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   Date  Apple Banana Orange  `NA`
#>   <chr> <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
#> 1 1-1       2      1      2     4
#> 2 1-2       1      1      0     4
#> 3 1-3       1      1      1     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We could use `base R` with `table` - `unlist` the 'product' columns to a `vector` while `rep`licating the 'Date' by the number of 'product' columns and use `table`

```
table(rep(df1$Date, 3), unlist(df1[3:5]))
     
      Apple Banana Orange
  1-1     2      1      2
  1-2     1      1      0
  1-3     1      1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with pivoting: @akrun: I tried `values_fill = list(n = 0)` but gives Error: Can't convert  to .

```
df %>% 
  select(-Transaction) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -Date
  ) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  add_count(value) %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = value,
    values_from = n, 
    values_fn = list
  ) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(Apple, Banana, Orange)) %>% 
  distinct()
```

```
  Date  Apple Banana Orange
  <chr> <int>  <int>  <int>
1 1-1       2      1      2
2 1-2       1      1     NA
3 1-3       1      1      1
```